# What is the difference between a break point with argument for condition, and a condition break point?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, pdb

From The Python Library Reference:

> **b(reak) [[ﬁlename:]lineno | function[, condition]]**
>
> With a lineno
> argument, set a break there in the current ﬁle. With a function
> argument, set a break at the ﬁrst executable statement within that
> function. The line number may be preﬁxed with a ﬁlename and a colon,
> to specify a breakpoint in another ﬁle (probably one that hasn’t been
> loaded yet). The ﬁle is searched on sys.path. Note that each
> breakpoint is assigned a number to which all the other breakpoint
> commands refer.
>
> *If a second argument is present, it is an expression
> which must evaluate to true before the breakpoint is honored.*
>
> Without
> argument, list all breaks, including for each breakpoint, the number
> of times that breakpoint has been hit, the current ignore count, and
> the associated condition if any.
>
> **condition bpnumber [condition]**
>
> *Condition is an expression which must evaluate to true before the
> breakpoint is honored.* If condition is absent, any existing condition
> is removed; i.e., the breakpoint is made unconditional.

What is the difference between a break point with second argument for condition (the first part in the quote), and a condition break point (the second part in the quote)? They look the same to me from the quote.

Answer (score 0):

The **b** command defines a breakpoint. You can specify a condition, but you needn't do so.

The **condition** commands needs a breakpoint that is already defined (i.e. needs a **b** command before) and changes the condition of it.

The following two debugger commands can be considered equal:

```
b debugme:3,x==100
```

and

```
b debugme:3
condition 1 x==100
```

Let's go practical:

Create the following Python script and name it `debugme.py`:

```
def myfunction():
    for x in range(0,200):
        print x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfunction()
```

Walkthrough of syntax 1 (**b** with condition):

```
C:\tmp\py>C:\Python27\python.exe
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pdb
>>> import debugme
>>> pdb.run('debugme.myfunction()')
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) b debugme:3,x==100                               <---- note this line
Breakpoint 1 at c:\tmp\py\debugme.py:3
(Pdb) c
0
1
2
3
...
97
98
99
> c:\tmp\py\debugme.py(3)myfunction()
-> print x
(Pdb) p x
100
(Pdb) q
>>> exit()
```

Walkthrough of syntax 2 (**b** without condition plus **condition**):

```
C:\tmp\py>C:\Python27\python.exe
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pdb
>>> import debugme
>>> pdb.run('debugme.myfunction()')
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) b debugme:3                                     <---- note this line
Breakpoint 1 at c:\tmp\py\debugme.py:3
(Pdb) b
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at c:\tmp\py\debugme.py:3
(Pdb) condition 1 x==100                              <---- and this one
(Pdb) b
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at c:\tmp\py\debugme.py:3
        stop only if x==100
(Pdb) c
0
1
2
3
...
97
98
99
> c:\tmp\py\debugme.py(3)myfunction()
-> print x
(Pdb) p x
100
(Pdb) q
>>> exit()
```